# Java parsing json array, Error parsing data org.json.JSONException

Tags: java, php, json, arraylist

This is my code, in my log, i'm getting:

> E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException Value xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

I really need a solution i have been searching for weeks now.

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... para) {

        List<NameValuePair> params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json=jparser.makeHttpRequest(getDataUrl, "POST", params);

        try {
            success=json.getInt("success");
            if(success==1){

                drivers=new ArrayList<Driver>();

                JSONArray sounds=json.getJSONArray("location");
                for (int i = 0; i < sounds.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jobj=sounds.getJSONObject(i);
                    Driver d=new Driver();
                    d.setId(jobj.getString("id"));
                    d.setName(jobj.getString("name"));
                    d.setEmail(jobj.getString("email"));
                    d.setNumber(jobj.getString("number"));
                    d.setLatitude(jobj.getString("latitude"));
                    d.setLongitude(jobj.getString("longitude"));
                    d.setInfo(jobj.getString("info"));
                    d.setCost(jobj.getString("cost"));
                    drivers.add(d);

                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            error=1;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            error=1;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And this is the JSONParser class

#### JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // check for request method
            if(method.equals("POST")){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } else if(method.equals("GET")) {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

#### PHP File

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once 'core/db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$sql="SELECT * FROM locations WHERE online=1";
$result = mysqli_query($db->connect(), $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db->connect()));

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
    $response["location"] = array();
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $files=array();
            $files["id"]=$row["id"];
            $files["name"]=$row["name"];
            $files["email"]=$row["email"];
            $files["number"]=$row["number"];
            $files["latitude"]=$row["latitude"];
            $files["longitude"]=$row["longitude"];
            $files["info"]=$row["vehicleinfo"];
            $files["cost"]=$row["costpkm"];

            array_push($response["location"], $files);

    }

    $response["success"]=1;
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["success"]=0;
    $response["message"]="No Taxi found";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you post the JSON you're trying to parse?

Comment: i just did...please help

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, the return result for makeHttpRequest is an xml object instead of json formated string.

Comment: actually, it's a json formatted string, but still i don't know the problem

Comment: Can you post the result for makeHttpRequest()?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

> the error was due to incorrect url, the xampp apache server was returning an object not found page..error 404, which is an xml file. That's why the return result for makeHttpRequest is an xml object instead of json formated string.